# Checking if panel has moved during MouseDown

Tags: c#, panels

I have a panel, that can be moved left or right (chosen automatically according to its current position, distance is static) by **click**. Also, the user can drag the panel vertically however he wants by clicking the panel, **holding the button and moving his mouse**. The problem is, that the panel does the left/right move also, when it is dropped after being moved vertically, so the user has to click it again afterwards, to get to correct side (left/right). Here are the methods I am using:
Adding eventhandlers to panel(called Strip here)

```
Strip.MouseDown += new MouseEventHandler(button_MouseDown);
Strip.MouseMove += new MouseEventHandler(button_MouseMove);
Strip.MouseUp += new MouseEventHandler(button_MouseUp);
Strip.Click += new EventHandler(strip_Click);
```

And here all the methods mentioned above:

```
void button_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        activeControl = sender as Control;
        previousLocation = e.Location;
        Cursor = Cursors.Hand;
    }

void button_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        if (activeControl == null || activeControl != sender)
            return;

        var location = activeControl.Location;
        location.Offset(0, e.Location.Y - previousLocation.Y);
        activeControl.Location = location;
    }

void button_MouseUp(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        activeControl = null;
        Cursor = Cursors.Default;
    }

void strip_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) // The one moving strip to left or right
    {
        activeControl = sender as Control;
            if (activeControl.Left != 30)
                activeControl.Left = 30;
            else
                activeControl.Left = 5;
    }
```

How to make the panel not move left or right when it was moved vertically?

Comment: How to make the panel not move left or right when it was moved vertically.

Comment: @HansPassant Tried replacing 0 with 1, as soon as I click the panel, it starts moving to the right. It stops when I release the mouse button, but I cant get it back anyway. I just need something like "if location.y changed -> keep the location.x the same (so dont apply the strip_click)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll need to distinguish between a click and a drag.  So add a private field named "dragged".

```
    private bool dragged;
```

In the MouseDown event handler add:

```
    dragged = false;
```

In the MouseMove event handler add:

```
    if (Math.Abs(location.Y - previousLocation.Y) > 
        SystemInformation.DoubleClickSize.Height) dragged = true;
```

In the Click event handler add:

```
    if (dragged) return;
```

Comment: Strange, now I cant move the panel at all. Maybe its because of this: as there are more panels with this thing applied, I am saving the "dragged" as invisible label in each of them, set to string "0", changing to "1" when in the "if" in MouseMove, and back to "0" in MouseDown. When i click the panel, it still moves left or right just fine, but I cant move it vertically now.

Comment: Just figured out that what I did is a total non-sense. I'm sorry. Now applied your code with the bool variable, but I get the same result - after I hold the mouse button and move the mouse, the strip doesn't move.
**BUT**, when I move the mouse at least it doesnt move horizontally :)

Comment: These are just inserted statements, they don't prevent the assignment to the Location property in the MouseMove event.  Which is what makes the panel move.  I can't guess how you got it wrong.